# Migrating from db in postgis 1.5 to db in postgis 2.5

Tags: postgis, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-11

I have 2 servers with 2 postgresql. 
Server 1 has postgresql 8.4 and server 2 has postgresql 11.4.

I want to migrate databases from server 1 to server 2. However on server 1 has postgis 1.5 and server 2 has postgis 2.5.

Which means when I try to import databases I have an error concerning postgis version because it can't find the file, I get the following error message :

`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERREUR:  n'a pas pu accéder au fichier « $libdir/postgis-1.5 » : No such file or directory
        Command was: CREATE FUNCTION public.box2d_in(cstring) RETURNS public.box2d
        LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
        AS '$libdir/postgis-1.5', 'BOX2DFLOAT4_in';`

I was thinking to migrate postgis version from 1.5 to 2.5 of server 1 and then restore databases into server 2. But this way means a postgis 1.5 unsitall and 2.5 install.

I'd like to know if there is another way to do ?

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: I _think_ you need to first install PostGIS 1.5 on the target server, then import your dump, then upgrade PostGIS to 2.5

Comment: I can't do that because the target server is in production

Comment: Then your idea of first upgrading the old server to postgis 2.5 is probably the only chance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, thanks for helping !